# Correct usage of fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmenttransaction

I'm sure this question has been asked lots of times but didn't find any useful answer.

I'm trying to implement Fragment which can be use in my app for X times (yes yes..even 100 and more..)

I want to create my fragment only once and in other times to pass bundle and make lifecycle do what he needs to do with the bundle data.
So far so good? So what i've found is a nice implementation from google document:

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {

public MyFragment() { }  // Required empty constructor

public static MyFragment newInstance(String foo, int bar) {
MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(ARG_FOO, foo);
args.putInt(ARG_BAR, bar);
f.setArguments(args);
return f;
}
```

You can then access this data at a later point:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle args = getArguments();
if (args != null) {
// Use initialisation data
}
}
```

So what's wrong here? First, the Fragment **MUST** be an inner class. Second, if the class is static, and the function newInstance(...) is static, why they always create new instance without checking (By keeping a static member of the fragment) if it's not null like a **Singleton** ?

**Assuming my fragment will be added many times to my fragment manager, can I use my fragment class as full Singleton**? it means that each time I'll call:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private static MyFragment sInstance;

public MyFragment() { }  // Required empty constructor

public static MyFragment newInstance(String foo, int bar) {
if (sInstance==null) {
  sInstance = new MyFragment();
}
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(ARG_FOO, foo);
args.putInt(ARG_BAR, bar);
f.setArguments(args);
return f;
}

}
```

Than use the new/exist fragment to make the transaction.

Hope I make myself clear, and didn't write some nonsense here :)

Thanks very much for your help